# redirect to another page rather than index after sign in via passport in MEAN.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using MEAN.js to create a CRUD web application.
in this app I use passport for Authentication

It redirect to the index page after signing in
But how can I redirect to another page like my module page?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `authenticate`(http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate)

Use it as a route handler

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('facebook', function(error, user, info){
  if (error) {
    log.error(error);
    next(error);
  } else {
    if (user) {
      // do the redirect here
    } else {
      next(new Error("Invalid Request"));
    }
  }
}));
```

Or as a middleware

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'),
  function(req, res) {
    // do redirect here
  });
```

Or use options

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/user',
                               failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

Comment: Yeah But I cannot find it in the MEAN.js File
where Should I look for it?

Comment: I took a look at MEAN.js, it seems like a generator. You can just overwrite the default route that they provide (https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/app/routes/users.server.routes.js). In my opinion, you should start with using Express directly